# How to solve this ODE?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, ode

I have encountered a problem in this equation whether I use `odeint` or `solve_ivp` to solve.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def ODE(E, p):
    u, v = p
    n = 3.25
    dudE = v
    dvdE = -(u**n)-(2*v/E)
    return [dudE, dvdE]

P0 = [1,0]
solve = solve_ivp(ODE, (0.001,10), P0, t_eval=np.linspace(0.001,10,500))
```

I cannot let the `n=3.25` or `n=0.25` etc. It have an error like

```
Project_q2d.py:19: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  dvdE = -(u**n)-(2*v/E)
```

But if let `n` is an integer it will run perfectly without any problem.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `u` becomes negative during the solving. For integer values of `n` this is fine, but for a non-integer `n` the exponentiation will have to be performed by either

1. Representing the exponent as a reduced fraction, taking a denominator-order root of the base and raising the result to the numerator.
2. Using an approach like that in [this answer on Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/21386/625953)

For a negative base, the result in the first case will be imaginary if the denominator is even and real only if it is odd and the result in the second case will always be imaginary.

This simple solution is to initialize `P0` with imaginary components,

```py
P0 = [1 + 0j, 0 + 0j]
```

---

**Note**  -  In Python 2.7 the `pow` function must be used for the exponentiation, in Python 3.x either the `**` operator or the `pow` function can be used.

Comment: Thank you! But when I try to plot the result the `plt.plot(E,u)` where `E = solve.t` and `u, v = solve.y`. It gives an error like `c:\users\matth\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py:538: ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)` . But it still can plot the graph, what is the error about?

Comment: @MatthewFong That warning is because there is an imaginary part to the result, it still plots the graph because there is also a real part - that is the part it is plotting. It raises a warning though because it is discarding the complex part and if it didn't give a warning there would be no indication any complex part exists. Unless you are interested in the complex part of the result it is not something to be concerned by (in this case at least)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the ersatz problem

```
u'' + 2*u'/E + u*abs(u)^(n-1)
```

which gives the same solution as long as `u` stays positive, which happens to be up to about `E=8`.

[image]